# BigQuery: How to get the value of specific filed in a column?

Tags: sql, google-bigquery, bigdata

I have a table with three columns. I want to ***extract the specific field from each column*** and add them. E.g I want to add 2, 33 and 111.

[image: Table with 3 columns]

What is the efficient/optimised way to do so in BigQuery?

Thanks.

Comment: Do you actually have a column called `Row`?  And if not, then what is determining that order?

Comment: Row is not a column. BigQuery is just storing the data in that way.

Comment: Then you need to tell us how to generate this order.  The order you are seeing should not be relied upon.  Do you want the `S1` column to determine the order?

Comment: I am generating that table using this query. 
https://imgur.com/a/hyLk9IT

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One option is a pivot approach, something like this:

```
SELECT
    MAX(CASE WHEN Row = 2 THEN S1 END) +
    MAX(CASE WHEN Row = 3 THEN S2 END) +
    MAX(CASE WHEN Row = 1 THEN S3 END) AS the_sum
FROM yourTable;
```

If you don't actually have a `Row` column, then we can easily generate one in a CTE using one of the other columns to provide the ordering, e.g.

```
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT *,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY S1) Row
    FROM yourTable
)
```

Then, use the first query I gave above, but with `cte` as the table, instead of `yourTable`.

Here is a demo in SQL Server which at least shows the basic logic works:

### Demo

Comment: I just used that table to understand the concept. In reality, I have a very large dataset with more than 10 columns and I don't think this solution is scalable.

Comment: @John I think you're trying to use a SQL table like an Excel spreadsheet, and that implies bad design, not that my query is bad.

Comment: Brother, your query is awesome :). I really appreciate it. But as I mentioned I am learning bigquery/sql concepts, so can you please tell me what is the better way/design to do so. :)

Comment: It's hard for me to comment further.  What happens with the answers given here as you get more columns?  Why do they fail/become unusable?

Comment: It worked. My apology for not understanding your query. Thanks one again. Stay blessed :)

Answer (score 0):

I would write this as:

```
select sum(case when row = 1 then s3
                when row = 2 then s1
                when row = 3 then s2
           end)
from t;
```

I don't think you can be more optimized than an aggregation with no `group by`.

Comment: I just used that table to understand the concept. In reality, I have a very large dataset with more than 10 columns and I don't think this solution is scalable.

Comment: Thanks brother. :)

Comment: @john . . . How is this not "scalable"?